# Docker wont build image (or at least wont return image name), prompts 'docker scan'?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Above is my dockerfile. Pretty straightforward coming from this tutorial I watched. But when I ran the same command to build, that is: docker build .

it returns this:

```
[+] Building 3.8s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                          
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 134B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                         3.7s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                            0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:d82f1c3ab27a01bd49f963ff4d24ef868852da6d3780d9d42e93b03f4fa3f62a          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 701B                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] COPY . /app                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [4/4] RUN npm install                                                                                       0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:8f53182e56912caee1bedd5a6137ced5c947cecc7ad90bab7eff7a3ce1fc582c
```

I should be expecting some docker image name, I believe, to proceed with docker run <image_name>, but yet can't seem to find any name, even after I do ps -a. Please help, thanks

Comment: `docker build .` you didn't give it a tag so the image doesn't have one, only its inherent sha identifier.  You want `docker build -t name .` to give the image `name` tag

Answer (score 1):

You should add a tag name when you re building.

You can add a tag with -t.

```
docker build -t <tag-name> .
```

Note : This dockerfile working on /app direction and after that copying it in /app direction again. so your working direction is /app/app/-your-app-

you can fix this with

`COPY . .`